# How to log query string parameters with Postman

Tags: testing, logging, console, postman, querystringparameter

I'm using the tests of Postman to log into the console some of the details included in a JSON response.
The part of the test that logs is the following:

```
var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);

if (data.result[0] !== undefined) {
console.log(data.result[0].number, "|", data.result[0].category;    
}
else console.log(QUERYSTRING_PARAMETER, "is not present");
```

I've tried many sintaxes/formats to have the value of the QUERYSTRING_PARAMETER passed to the test. However when data.result is empty with every sintax I've tried, the test simply logs QUERYSTRING_PARAMETER not defined. How can I pass the value from the query string parameters in the URL to the test to be evaluated/logged?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it corresponds to what you need, but if you want data from your query, you may use the 'request' object (refer to [the Postman sandbox, paragraph 'Request/response related properties'](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman_sandbox)). 
You can get request method, url, headers and (maybe the one for you) data.

Alexandre